# What are these generic looking activities from sp_who2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to determine whether a sql server instance is actually in use, or just sitting there. It has no user databases, just the normal system databases and `distribution`. I'm fairly sure there is nothing happening, but it is in our production environment, so I can't just switch it off without being sure.

I have set up an agent job to run sp_who2 and log to a table every minute to see if I can catch any activity. I have the following rows, but nothing else (except stuff with my name on it!). They all look fairly generic - like it's the agent doing it's thing - but I'd just like to check first.

Are these jobs likely to be anything more than generic jobs doing nothing except checking to see if there's something to do?

```
DBName  Command ProgramName
msdb    AWAITING COMMAND    SQLAgent - Email Logger                                                  
master  SELECT INTO         SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x988FC626DDAAEE4D8F49FC83540F48A5 : Step 1)
msdb    AWAITING COMMAND    SQLAgent - Alert Engine                                                  
msdb    AWAITING COMMAND    DatabaseMail - SQLAGENT - Id<19792>                                      
msdb    AWAITING COMMAND    SQLAgent - Generic Refresher                                             
msdb    AWAITING COMMAND    SQLAgent - Job invocation engine                                         
msdb    SELECT              SQLAgent - Alert Engine                                                  
msdb    AWAITING COMMAND    SQL Management                                                           
msdb    AWAITING COMMAND    SQLAgent - Job Manager                                                   
msdb    UPDATE              SQLAgent - Schedule Saver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of that appears to be the result of normal Sql Agent activity.

Assuming you don't have any '*real (non-system)*' Sql Agent job running (meaning you don't really need the Sql Agent running), my suggestion would be to create a Windows Task scheduler process using `SQLCMD` to run your sp_who2 process on your defined interval and then **STOP** the Sql Agent.  What gets logged into your table then?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use sp_who2, which will litter your logging table with confusing junk like that, you should use Adam Machanic's [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) instead. It filters that stuff out (unless you tell it not to), and focuses on user space queries.

As for logging it to a table, it can be done [pretty easily](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/logging-activity-using-sp_whoisactive-take-2/) -- full disclosure, that blog post was written by my co-worker, Tara.

Hope this helps, and good luck with the ghost server.